# currentTime not working as intended. I'm not getting something here

Tags: javascript, video

I do not understand why this:

```
myVid1=document.getElementById("video1");
var trigger = 5;
var timecheck = myVid1.currentTime;


if(timecheck==trigger){
alert("AWESOME");
};
```

Does not work. Surely at 5 seconds the if statement should trigger? I mean, I don't get why it won't work this way either:

```
if(myVid1.currentTime=="5"){
    alert("AWESOME");
    };
```

Comment: How do you run that code?

Comment: What element is myVid1? Does it have `currentTime` property indeed?

Comment: @kidwon: Presumably it's an [`HTMLVideoElement`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-video-element), which inherits from [`HTMLMediaElement`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#htmlmediaelement), and thus has a [`currentTime` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#dom-media-currenttime).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean 'how do I run the code'. I write it and it runs. I expected that if the timecheck variable ever became equal to the trigger variable then the if statement would trigger... but I'm wrong and I don't know why

Comment: @user2021641: *"I'm not sure what you mean 'how do I run the code'. I write it and it runs"* Er, no. JavaScript client-side code runs *in response to something* (e.g., some event). That event can be the `script` getting processed during the initial page rendering, it can be a `load` event of some kind, etc., etc. If you're literally just dumping that in a `script` tag, you're only looking at the time **once**, and it's very unlikely to just happen to be exactly `5` seconds into the video.

Comment: Ah, now I see what you mean. I realize now there is nothing actually to make that code run at the correct time, thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

I see at least two problems with that code:

1. You seem to only be executing the `if` statement once, so if the media doesn't happen to be at the time you want during that one check, naturally the condition will be false. You probably want to respond to one of the events on the video's associated [`MediaController`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#mediacontroller), almost certainly [`timeupdate`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#handler-mediacontroller-ontimeupdate).
2. You're looking for a value of **exactly** `5`. But the odds are not high that you'd happen to catch **exactly** the value `5`. Remember that [`currentTime`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#dom-media-currenttime) is a floating-point number. Recommend looking for `myVid1.currentTime > 5` for any time after five seconds, or `myVid1.currentTime >= 5 && myVid1.currentTime < 6` if you only want a time within that fifth second.

So something like:

```
myVid1=document.getElementById("video1");
var trigger = 5;
myVid1.controller.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
    if (myVid1.currentTime >= trigger) {
        // Do something, note that this will happen again and again unless
        // you set a flag or remove the handler
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 for timeupdate. But @T.J. the time will update every millisecond and event will fire for each millisecond?

Comment: @AspiringAqib: I'll assume the event will get raised in a reasonable fashion, almost certainly **not** every millisecond.

Comment: you can also use `parseInt()` function if currentTime is floating point number ;) ahh also think my answer was not good.

Comment: Hey. Thanks a lot. This is actually for a looping sound element which is going to make a difference. How can I make the code fire once, then go back to it 'searching' state?

Comment: @user2021641: I'm not following what you mean.

Comment: Basically the code is for a looping audio element. I need my code to fire at X point in the audio file, and continually fire at that point in perpetuity.

Comment: @user2021641: You just need to throw a couple of state flags into it. For instance, start off with a flag `fired` which is `false`. When you see `>= 5` and `fired` is `false`, do your thing and set `fired` to `true`. If you see a time `< 5`, set `fired` back to `false` so you're primed again.